Как на виртуальную машину Windows 7 накатить qt версии 5.15.2?
Как на виртуальную машину Windows 7 накатить qt версии 5.15.2
И алгоритм действий пожалуйста.
Пробовал эти все проги накатить, не получилось собрать. На команды не реагирует.


https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer

Не берусь утверждать, что это точно сработает, т.к. на windows 7 уже давно не сидел (тем более, что это виртуалка), но вот можете попробовать это сделать через MSYS:

установить последнюю версию MSYS, которая поддерживает 7 винду


Последний релиз, полный установщик которого поддерживает Windows 7, находится здесь. Просто нажмите «Assets» и загрузите полный установщик.


И вот тут есть видео по установке через MSYS.

Еще раз повторюсь: я не могу быть уверен, т.к. у вас достаточно частный случай, но, надеюсь, вам это поможет.
